# Using addPopover in modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I am trying to use `addPopover` from `shinyBS` and I cannot get it to work in a module. The tooltip works fine in the module but the popover doesn't show up. Also, both tooltip and popover work fine when placed directly in the main `server` section. Tested with `shiny_1.3.2` and `shinyBS_0.61` on R 3.6.1 and RStudio 1.2.1568.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
     actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
     bsTooltip(id = ns("button"), title = "Info about the button"),
     verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

counter <- function(input, output, session) {

  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    count(count() + 1)
  })

  output$out <- renderText({
    count()
  })

  addPopover(session, 
             id = "out", 
             title = "Info", 
             content = "More info about the counter field", 
             trigger = "hover")
  count
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  counterButton("counter1", "Counter #1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(counter, "counter1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `session$ns`:

```
counter <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    count(count() + 1)
  })

  output$out <- renderText({
    count()
  })

  addPopover(session, 
             id = ns("out"), 
             title = "Info", 
             content = "More info about the counter field", 
             trigger = "hover")
  #count # what's that?
}
```

Comment: My tooltip is created on a form that is called from a module. Both the module and form use shiny::NS(id)